# Awesome-WM inside gnome-shell -> Get rid of top panels

Tags: gnome, awesome

I am using awesome-wm now, and was trying to get it working with gnome-shell. I have basically followed those steps: 
http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome#Ubuntu_11.10

But now I have two panels, one at the bottom and one at the top. Is there any way to get rid of one of those (preferring top panels). If that is not possible, is there a way to load the gnome-shell applets in the top panel? Now it's only displaying the time.

screen: [image: http://i.imgur.com/5sqTv.png]

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

Quote from the same wiki page you linked:

"You will likely want to choose either gnome-panel or awesome's main wibox as your panel. If you choose to disable your wibox, configure your rc.lua to not start it up. If you choose to disable gnome-panel, it is easiest to stop using gnome-session and run your session in the traditional way."

Comment: To add on to that, the system tray is probably inside Awesome's wibox which is under the gnome panel, so I would disable Awesome's wibox because presumably one of the main reasons you're using Awesome inside Gnome instead of standalone is to get the gnome panel stuff.